# XSL analyze-string difficulty with tokenized strings

Tags: regex, xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, tokenize

I need to tokenize a string and then run `analyze-string` on each of the tokens. This, however, seems impossible:

> "XPTY0020: Required item type of the context item for the child axis
>   is node(); supplied value has item type xs:string) because
>   analyze-string requires a node context".

This is driving me insane, because `analyze-string` should, well, analyze strings, so I don't understand how to go around this problem.

My (simplified) XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rows>
    <row>
        <field name="def">1) ἀλλά sed, vero 2) καί et 3) а cum condicionali iunctum aequiparat
            аште: 4) ἵνα ut chron.</field>
    </row>
    <row>
        <field name="def">ἡλοῦν clavo figere</field>
    </row>
</rows>
```

and my stylesheet looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="2.0">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="field[@name = 'def']">
        <entry>
            <xsl:call-template name="sense">
                <xsl:with-param name="def" select="."/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </entry>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="sense">
        <xsl:param name="def"/>
        <xsl:param name="separator" select="'\d{1,2}\)\s'"/>

        <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(normalize-space($def), $separator)">
            <xsl:if test="string-length(.) > 0">
                <xsl:element name="sense">
                    <xsl:attribute name="n">
                        <xsl:value-of select="position() - 1"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <!--this is the problematic bit, because current() is 
                    a string here -\- and, paradoxically, analyze-string
                    cannot deal with it-->
                    <xsl:analyze-string select="current()"
                        regex="^([\p{IsGreek}\p{IsGreekExtended}]+[\s]*[\p{IsGreek}\p{IsGreekExtended}]*)(.*$)">
                        <xsl:matching-substring>
                            <greek>
                                <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)"/>
                                <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(2)"/>
                            </greek>
                        </xsl:matching-substring>
                        <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                            <xsl:value-of select="current()"/>
                        </xsl:non-matching-substring>
                    </xsl:analyze-string>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Without the problematic of `analyze-string`, the above stylesheet will correctly produce the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entry xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <sense n="1">ἀλλά sed, vero </sense>
   <sense n="2">καί et </sense>
   <sense n="3">а cum condicionali iunctum aequiparat аште: </sense>
   <sense n="4">ἵνα ut chron.</sense>
</entry>
<entry xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <sense n="0">ἡλοῦν clavo figere</sense>
</entry>
```

The stylesheet uses the `tokenize()` method in order to separate multiple senses. Then, for each of the identified senses, I want to use `analyze-string` to wrap the first greek word with `<greek></greek>`.

What workaround can I use to make `analyze-string` work on tokens, i.e. strings, rather than nodes?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: The error message is misleading. [The `xsl:analyze-string` instruction takes as input a string](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#analyze-string). The real problem is with your regex expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that the `regex` attribute allows attribute value templates so your curly braces need to be doubled to say

```
regex="^([\p{{IsGreek}}\p{{IsGreekExtended}}]+[\s]*[\p{{IsGreek}}\p{{IsGreekExtended}}]*)(.*$)"
```

Or you need to define the pattern outside in a variable e.g.

```
<xsl:variable name="pattern">^([\p{IsGreek}\p{IsGreekExtended}]+[\s]*[\p{IsGreek}\p{IsGreekExtended}]*)(.*$)</xsl:variable>
```

and use `regex="{$pattern}"`.

Comment: More particularly, what has probably happened here is that the processor has seen `{IsGreek}`, interprets the text within the curly braces as an XPath expression, decides that it means `child::IsGreek`, and then complains because `child::IsGreek` makes no sense when the context item is a string.

Comment: @michael.hor257k, I saw a similar error message there together with a warning that some file relating to Unicode classes could not be loaded so I think the problem there is with the particular installation and configuration of Saxon. I can run that code fine with Saxon 9.6 inside oXygen and as well with  Saxon 9.7 HE from the command line.

Comment: @michael.hor257k No I can't explain it. The site claims to be using Saxon-HE 9.5.1.6, but they may have modified it to reduce the threats from executing untrusted stylesheets. It's rejecting all block names (so it's not the "Greek" versus "GreekAndCoptic" issue - the block name changed in Unicode 3.2). I would expect a message if the data file containing the block details can't be loaded.

Comment: Thank you both. It's too bad the only decent online test application has this flaw - not to mention being offline so often.